# Drawing on click with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I already have a 10X10 grid of squares and I want to draw another square over a square in the grid when it is clicked.

Right now, I have functions to draw the grid in a frame and functions to determine the coordinates of the square (the upper left corners and lower right corner).

The part I'm having trouble with is

```
    canvas=Canvas()
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(10):
            canvas.create_rectangle(10+(row*53),10+(column*53),60+(row*53),60+(column*53),fill='blue')
    self.bind('<Button-1>',self.changeBlock)
```

where

```
def changeBlock(self,event):
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(upperX(event),upperY(event),lowerX(event),lowerY(event),fill='red')
```

upperX,upperY,lowerX,lowerY are all functions to determine the coordinates of the square that the mouse is in.

I dont know why changeBlock doesn't run when I click something on the canvas.

Full:

```
class MainFrame(Frame):
def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent,background="blue")
    self.parent=parent
    self.parent.title("simple")
    self.parent.geometry("600x600")
    self.parent.resizable(0,0)
    self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    canvas=Canvas()
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(10):
            canvas.create_rectangle(10+(row*53),10+(column*53),60+(row*53),60+(column*53),fill='blue')
    self.bind('<Button-1>',self.changeClickBlock)
    canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, a slight modification of yours. You did not provide **quite** enough information, but it was enough to see that things ... should be working. I'm running python3 - in python2, you'd import from "Tkinter".

**Important questions**:

- what is "self" - what class did you define? If self doesn't derive
  some kind of tkinter widget, then binding to it won't do much good.
  Does bind throw an exception?

  You also didn't save a reference to your canvas, so how do you know
  what self.canvas is later? Pretty confusing, but I assume you just
  didn't post the whole code.

**Probable Problems**:

- My main guess is that you didn't bind to the canvas, but somewhere
  else. Make sure that the event triggers on the widget you want it to.

  My second guess is that you forgot to pack/grid/place the canvas in
  the tkinter toplevel. Simply making it is not enough, you also need
  to add it to the scene somehow

  ```
  from tkinter import *

  root = Tk()
  canvas=Canvas() # where did you save this? It's very important to keep it!

  def changeBlock( event=None ): 
          # Here, I'm just making a rectangle of size 10. Make it as big as you want
          # notice though that you're "self.canvas" will need to reference the
          # the right thing
          canvas.create_rectangle(event.x,event.y,event.x+10,event.y+10,fill='red')

  for row in range(10):
      for column in range(10):
          canvas.create_rectangle(10+(row*53),10+(column*53),60+(row*53),60+(column*53),fill='blue')

  # Here, I'm binding to the Canvas. Bind to the widget where the event occurs
  canvas.bind('<Button-1>',changeBlock)  

  # make sure you add the widget somehow, or else it won't appear
  canvas.grid()  

  root.mainloop()
  ```

**Other Suggestions**

Effobt has a great tutorial on tkinter. It's a great place to look for basic examples

On canvas items:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

On events:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem that I have. When I run my code and click on any of the squares, it doesn't call changeBlock at all. I put print statements in changeBlock and they don't run when I click.

Comment: Run the code I just gave you, it works. Why are you binding to self? You should bind to canvas. The canvas cannot be on self, unless self extends Tk which is extremely unorthodox. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok The problem was that I binded the button to self instead of the canvas. now it works. Thank You!